# How to include @ (at sign) as part of filename in OSX terminal (SVN Command)?

Tags: macos, unix, command-line

I'm surprised I haven't been able to find an answer to this after googling for half-an-hour.

My filename is Default-LandscapeRight@2x.png but it cuts of the filename at the '@' sign (*can't find file 'Default-LandscapeRight'*) within the OSX Terminal when entering a command.
I tried escaping it with a slash in front, i tried putting the whole filename in single quotes but it does not do the trick.

Anyone?

*Edit:* I'm trying to add a file using SVN (Subversion).
svn add Default-LandscapeRight@2x.png

Comment: Same result. Cuts off at @.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181852/how-do-i-escape-character-in-mac

Comment: That did the trick! And I was using SVN yes (add command). Post it as an answer Colonel and I will give it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@@` to *escape* the character in SVN:

```
svn add Default-LandscapeRight@@2x.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `svn add 'Default-LandscapeRight@2x.png'@HEAD`.